# What is the most idiomatic way in Go to test code which has dependency on structure with big amount of methods?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

Lets say I have a UserRepository struct which incapsulates logic for interacting with a database. This struct has a set of methods like:

- findAll()
- findById()
- findByName()
- save()
- and so on....

There is another struct (let's call it UserService for instance) which depends on UserRepository struct.

To test UserService I need to mock functionality of UserRepository. The only way I know to do this is to provide the interface for UserRepository and make UserService be dependent on it instead of UserRepository struct. It will allow to create a mocked implementation of interface and set it as dependency of UserService in the test.

What is the most idiomatic way to do it?

1) If UserService depends only on 1 UserRepository's method (let's say findAll) - should I still define an interface which will have all repository methods or it's better to define a separate interface for this method only and use it as a dependency of UserService? If so, what is the best name for it (interface)? If another struct will depend on findAll() and findById() methods should I again create another interface?

2) Where is a best place to store mocks for these interfaces? Is it possible to reuse them? Or for tests of different structs I will need redefine the mocks?

P.S. as for me unit tests is a very important part of the project. I would like to make them as readable as possible avoiding boilerplate code and focusing on their logic. So creating several mock implementations for same interfaces in different test files looks for me a bad option since it makes test code less readable.

Comment: I don't know if this is considered idiomatic, but my gut instinct is to create an interface for UserRepository with the smallest surface area you need (only one method at the moment).  I would call the interface UserRepository and the struct something more specific to the implementation like MongoUserRepository if it was talking to MongoDb

Comment: You could create a file called something like `mocks_test.go` and keep your mocks in there.  As long as that file is in the same package as your other tests, they'll be able to use the mocks.  Again, I don't know if this would be considered idiomatic or not.

Comment: The problem is that with this approach I will end up with a lot of interfaces. One interface for FindAll() method. Another interface for FindByName() method. Third interface for combination of FindAll() and FindById() methods etc. And I cannot call them all UserRepository.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that.  Create one interface and put in as many methods as callers of the interface need. You shouldn't put in anything extra into the interface that isn't being called by another struct though.

Comment: It seems to me like you're trying to write Java in Go.

Answer (score 1):

1) I'd go with what elevine said, i.e. only require the methods that you need for that struct. So for example: you have `UserService` that needs `FindByName` and `FindAll`, and `UserAdminService` that needs `FindById`, `FindAll` and `Save`. In that case you should have two interfaces:

1. `UserProvider` with `FindByName` and `FindAll`
2. `UserAdminProvider` with `FindById`, `FindAll` and `Save`.

This also lets you keep your `UserProvider` in check, e.g. you know it can't call `Save`, so it can't modify a user.

You'll likely only need one actual implementation that satisfies both interfaces.

2) Check out [testify/mock](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock) and [mockery](https://github.com/vektra/mockery). Mockery will generate mocks for your interfaces in a `mocks` subpackage, one for each interface.
This does mean you can't use the same mock struct for both tests, but it doesn't matter, because the code is generated. You don't mock up the behavior of the interface in the mock struct, you do it in the test by setting up expectations, e.g.:

```
func TestThatYouCantLoginWithNonexistentUser(t *testing.T) {
    userRepository := new(mocks.UserRepository)
    userService := user.NewService(userRepository)
    // if the userService calls UserRepository.FindByName("joe"), it will return nil, since there's no such user.
    userRepository.On("FindByName", "joe").Return(nil)
    _, err := userService.Login("joe", "password")
    // err should not be nil and the message should be "user does not exist"
    assert.EqualError(t, err, "user does not exist")
    // assert that the expectations were met, i.e. FindByName was called with "joe"
    userRepository.AssertExpectations(t)
}
```

This actually makes the test easy to understand, since you don't have to go check in some other file what the mock does when you call `FindByName("joe")`.